# Query using group_concat is returning only one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is a query that is supposed to get the user's information, their project's information, and a group_concat of all the image paths that such project is associated to. To add to this, I am only getting the information mentioned from the people the user is following.

This is, however, **only retunring one row.**

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.user_id, projects.project_id, projects.project_name, projects.project_time, group_concat(images.image_path)
FROM users, projects, images
WHERE users.user_id = projects.user_id
AND users.user_id IN (SELECT follow_user_2 FROM following WHERE follow_user_1 = 1)
 ORDER BY projects.project_id DESC
```

**TO COMPARE:** The following query **WORKS** in the sense that in the loop it gives all of the user's information and the projects information related to such user.

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.user_id, projects.project_id, projects.project_name, projects.project_time 
    FROM users, projects
    WHERE users.user_id = projects.user_id 
    AND users.user_id IN (SELECT follow_user_2 FROM following WHERE follow_user_1 = 1)
    ORDER BY projects.project_id DESC
```

When I try to use group_concat it just returns me **one** row and I do not understand why.

Can someone help me please? Thank you. If my question was not clear enough, I will elaborate.

If this helps, here's an SQL FIDDLE.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/867f6/2
I had to shorten my schema a lot. Try both queries to above to see the problem.

Comment: what is this `follow_user_1 = 1`  condition applied for? Joining condition with `images` table seems missing.

Comment: @DipenduPaul that is actually $user_id instead of "1". It's dynamic.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> When I try to use group_concat it just returns me one row and I do not understand why.

Because you have not used the `GROUP BY` clause in your query. When using aggregate functions like `GROUP_CONCAT` you need to tell the database about the column using which you want your data to be combined.

Currently your query is grouping all records and giving 1 record in the output.

If you add `GROUP BY users.userid` in the query then the records will be grouped by unique userid's. I updated your fiddle and it now gives 2 records: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/867f6/18

Please note: In standard SQL queries, columns listed in the GROUP BY clause should match the column in the SELECT clause (except the aggregate functions).

Answer (score 7):

Just use `group by` clause in your_query

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, 
       users.user_id, projects.project_id, 
       projects.project_name, projects.project_time, 
       group_concat(images.image_path)
FROM users, projects, images
    WHERE users.user_id = projects.user_id 
    AND users.user_id IN (SELECT follow_user_2 FROM following 
                          WHERE follow_user_1 = 1)
    group by users.first_name
    ORDER BY projects.project_id DESC;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/867f6/20)

Comment: Thanks for including an example in your answer! I wasn't sure where the group by had to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't use `group by` clause in the query. So the DBMS will `group_concat` all rows in one row. Because there is `group by project_id` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
select json_group_array(json_object('shipment',ShipmentNo,'CreatedDateTime',CreatedDateTime)) as oujyu_name_list from outscan where flage='2'
```

```
Result : [{"CreatedDateTime":"2022-10-10 16:42:06","shipment":"456"},{"CreatedDateTime":"2022-10-10 16:42:06","shipment":"456457"},{"CreatedDateTime":"2022-10-10 16:42:06","shipment":"dfgdg"},{"CreatedDateTime":"2022-10-10 16:42:06","shipment":"4564fd"},{"CreatedDateTime":"2022-10-10 16:42:06","shipment":"456756nvjf"},{"CreatedDateTime":"2022-10-10 16:42:06","shipment":"457"},{"CreatedDateTime":"2022-10-10 16:42:06","shipment":"dfgdfg"},{"CreatedDateTime":"2022-10-10 16:42:06","shipment":"dfgdg"},{"CreatedDateTime":"2022-10-10 16:42:06","shipment":"dhf"}]
```