# How to translate the PostgreSQL array_agg function to SQLite?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, android-sqlite, aggregate-functions

This query works in PostgreSQL:

```
  Select    ot.MCode,array_to_string(array_agg(tk1.TName || ',' || ot.TTime), ' - ') as oujyu_name_list
    From    TR_A ot
    inner join MS_B tk1 on ot.Code = tk1.Code
    Where   ot.Code in (Select Code From TR_C ) 
    Group byot.MCode
```

but it does not work in SQLite, because SQLite does not have the `array_agg()` function.  How can this query be converted to SQLite?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For this query, you can use [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat), which directly returns a string:

```
SELECT ..., group_concat(tk1.TName || ',' || ot.TTime, ' - ')
FROM ...
```

Comment: it's worth to mention that unlike the ARRAY_AGG function, you must specify the GROUP_BY clause for GROUP_CONTACT, more infos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190200/query-using-group-concat-is-returning-only-one-row

Comment: @younes0 *All* aggregate functions return a single row without GROUP BY; there's no difference between ARRAY_AGG and GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: You're right; I was talking about the specific case postgres which allows to omit the group_by (if you query in one table I guess)

Comment: @younes0 *All* SQL databases allow to omit the GROUP BY (and then use one group over all rows when you're using any aggregate function).

Answer (score 9):

SQLite now has the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension (which ships in the default distribution) that can group and create arrays of JSON objects. For example,

```
select
  ot.MCode,
  json_group_array(json_object('tname', tk1.TName, 'ttime', ot.TTime)) as oujyu_name_list
from TR_A as ot
inner join MS_B as tk1
on (ot.Code = tk1.Code)
where ot.Code in (select code from TR_C)
group by ot.MCode;
```

The second column will be formatted as a JSON array e.g. `[{"tname":...,"ttime":...},...]`.